# Visual Studio 2010 removes reference upon compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference DLLs not loading in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997502/reference-dlls-not-loading-in-visual-studio-2010)

I'm working on an XNA project, in which I need a simple 2D particle effect system. I located [this](http://microstar.codeplex.com/releases/view/63168) one, which I downloaded and added a reference to in my project. However, when I compile my project, Visual Studio acts as if the reference isn't there, and proceeds to spit errors about "missing assembly reference". The reference is clearly in the References list, but when I look at the Object Browser, it's nowhere in sight. If I remove it and add it again, or alter something in the Properties box for the reference, it appears again in the Object Browser, only to vanish when I recompile.

This is a very frustrating issue, since I'm not doing anything wrong. There must be something with Visual Studio. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is the code I get errors on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MicroStar;

namespace GemSwap {
    public class GemTriggerParticleEffect : ParticleEffect {

        public GemTriggerParticleEffect() {

        }

    }
}
```

This gives the errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'MicroStar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'ParticleEffect' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are referencing the assembly.